# Flutter Easy Localization

Tags: flutter, dart

currently I am having an issue which I use easy_localization-1.3.3.

When I use it and get the translation via `AppLocalizations.of(context).tr('key_in_json_file');`

In the AppLocalization code base I see it use dart http to get the response of the i18n file in server

```
data = await http.get(localePath).then((response) => response.body.toString());
```

I debug and see the response.body always return bad UTF-8 characters.

However, my colleague not having this issue. We build same application but it seem that just me having this issue. Does anyone have any hint about this one?